# unable to search using custom Array Adapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am unable to search from `listview`, i tried various ways, but its not working for me(No Errors). I have other way to search but i want to make this way possible.

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher   {

CustomAdapter mAdapter;
ListView mListview;
EditText search;
List<String> tempCity, cityNames;
String list[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    init();

    bindComponents();

    addListeners();
}

private void addListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    search.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mPos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    tempCity = new ArrayList<String>();
    cityNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cityList);
    cityNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(list));


}



private void bindComponents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cityList);

    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTsearch);
    mListview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cityNames);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cityNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cityNames.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup vGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = v;

        if (row == null) {

            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_row, null);

        }

        TextView mCityTv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemTv);
        mCityTv.setText(cityNames.get(pos));

        return row;
    }

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
}
 }
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: What function is causing you trouble? Is it erroring or just misbehaving? Provide stacktrade for the former, details for the latter?

Comment: No Errors, just not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have to switch another way of searching by `Implementing Filterable` Class

Please see similar [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14260239/1278196) given by me

Answer (score 0):

1) Call `mListview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);` on the ListView to enable filtering

2) Create a relevant constructor for your `CustomAdapter` class. You'll need to pass it context as well as various resources/data. Read up on it:
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

**OR**

Use a `TextWatcher` [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355971/how-to-filter-listview-through-edittext).