# How to create search functionality in listview

Tags: android, search, listviewitem

I want to create search functionality in listview,i have a small doubt that using arraylist can we perform search functionality.Here i ahve attached the code..where the

Totalarraylist is the arraylist and from that arraylist i am passing the data to Question adapter class
code,,

```
    searchbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              @Override
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                  // When user changed the Text

              If so then what to add here for search functionality...

              }

              @Override
              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                      int arg3) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
          });


          adapterfirst = new Questionadapter(MainActivity.this,Totalarraylist);
      listviewfirst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listquestion);
      listviewfirst.setAdapter(adapterfirst);

}

public class  Questionadapter extends BaseAdapter  {

        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data;    
          public  LayoutInflater inflater;
            Context context;



        public Questionadapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> Totalarraylists) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            data=Totalarraylists;
              inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                System.out.println("data="+data);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //
}
}
```

could anybody help me to do this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403971/unable-to-search-using-custom-array-adapter-in-android

Comment: You don't search a listview, you search your datasource.

Comment: yes you can do it with the help of array list.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya how..can to help me..

Comment: @Mitesh you have used adapter class.i am telling about using arraylist can we do that

Comment: @Sangita I have done this already but right now I do not have code with me. I can provide you code in 1-2 days

Comment: @cjk yes,.if so then how to do that

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya thanks..can you edit the above code....

Comment: @Sangita i am using BaseAdapter, but we need adapter to bind the list. See [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Comment: @Mitesh when i try that the error is displaying..The method getFilter() is undefined for the type ListAdapter

Comment: please show your full code

Comment: @Mitesh i have attached my code..

Answer (score 0):

add a filter to your `ListAdapter`, and on `onTextChanged` apply the filter to `listadapter`

Comment: can you edit my code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Compare your array list with your string you will get answer

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

private EditText searchEdt;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // making it full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ugsimply_beta);

    list.add("Android");
    list.add("Android1");
    list.add("blackberry");
    list.add("samsung");
    list.add("LG");
    searchEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEdt);

    searchEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private int textlength;
        private ArrayList<String> arrayList_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            textlength = searchEdt.getText().length();
            if (arrayList_sort != null)
                arrayList_sort.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                if (textlength <= list.get(i).toString().length()) {

                    if (searchEdt
                            .getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) list.get(i).toString()
                                            .subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                        arrayList_sort.add(list.get(i));
                        Log.d("TAG", "log" + arrayList_sort.size());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: What is getUserName()..

Comment: i didn't get your code could you explain the code....

Comment: Arraylist value. what you stored in your array list.that value

Comment: what array list value ..i have stored multiple values in arraylist

Comment: you have store all values in array list. Use that array list value.

Comment: For example i have stored all values in mPhoneData arraylist. when i enter text in search edit box am getting length of text. Using that text length comparing arraylist.

Comment: i have stored everything in  single array list that i have mentioned in above code

Comment: I have edited please try in your eclipse.you will get solution

Comment: @thanks let me check...........

Comment: no i didn't get ...i have used custom adapter that extends base adapter

Comment: send your code i will try it

Comment: look i have edited my code..i want to ask that can we search the list item using arraylist ..without using arrayadapter or listadapter,,if so ,then how to do that../